# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in

Tags: php, memcached

php -v :

```
PHP 5.5.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Mar 27 2014 16:18:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with XCache Optimizer v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Cacher v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
    with XCache Coverager v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2013, by mOo
```

dpkg -l | grep php5

result

```
rc  php5-memcache                                   3.0.6-1                                             memcache extension module for PHP5
rc  php5-memcached                                  1.0.2-2                                             memcached extension module for PHP5, uses libmemcached
ii  php5-mysql                                      5.5.10+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1                MySQL module for php5
```

php.ini setting .

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;   memchached        ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/memcache.so
extension=memcached.so
memcache.hash_strategy="consistent"
```

but phpinfo not showing memchache details. 
and php script giving `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in`

Comment: Perhaps you are working in a autoloading namespaced environment [psr-0], try `\Memcached` wherever you are using it.

Comment: `php5-memcache` and `php5-memcached` aren't installed. the "rc" in the dpkg output means, that the packages have been uninstalled, and that the configuration has been kept.

Comment: `php -m` is good to see loaded modules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`php5-memcache` and `php5-memcached` aren't installed. the `"rc"` in the dpkg output means, that the packages have been uninstalled, and that the configuration has been kept.

Answer (score 3):

dpkg -l | grep php5 indicate that module is not install

`ii` means 'It should be installed and it is installed' whereas

`rc` means 'It's removed/uninstalled but it's configuration files are still there'

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to install 'Memcache'

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
```

Answer (score -2):

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found

the library might be missing, you can manually include the missing php_memcache into the ext folder

Comment: I have the same issue sucked with the mamcache error although i do "php_memcache.dll" in my windows7 machine at d:/xampp/php/ext (php version - 5.4.7) doesn't found the issue with the error that says, "Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found"